# Increase server response time

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-12.04

I was getting 52 out of 100 for speed when using Google PageSpeed Insight for the website I'm hosting. And I am trying to increase the server response time and I've been searching via Google. So far I found that I need to do some tweaking in my httpd.conf file such as KeepAlive and MaxRequestWorkers since I use httpd 2.4.12. I'm a bit paranoid when it comes to making changes in my httpd.conf. Do I need MPM worker to be able to include KeepAlive and MaxRequestWorkers? Or can I just add them to the conf file?

I run a quick command on my system (runs on Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS 32bit)

```
$ free -lm
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           999        926         72          0         11         73
Low:           869        798         70
High:          130        128          1
-/+ buffers/cache:        841        157
Swap:         5720        954       4766
```

I realize this is only 1G of RAM.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Don't you want to *decrease* the server response time?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest for decreasing the server response time is making use of wordpress caching plugins like Wp-super cache (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/).

This is the quickest solution to drastically bring down the Server response time. You may have to move the dynamic components to load via Ajax to prevent that section from returning the cached result.

These plugins are simple to use and give you better results on the speed front without much code tweaking

Comment: I apologize for asking the wrong question. It's meant to be reducing the server response time, not increasing. Thank you Roshni for guessing it right. Sorry about this. After trying the plugin wp-super-cache, it started to get a little faster than before. Still getting the message from google speed test that says "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". will do some digging. Anyhow, Thank you for your tips. I also happen to find another plugin called "wp3 cache".

Comment: My apology again. It's called w3 total cache.

Comment: You are welcome Daniel. To do away with 'Eliminate render blocking' messages you can combine all your js files in one group and all css in another and minify these(You have wordpress plugins to do these as well if its difficult for you). Try to defer load your javascripts as far as possible so that it does not come in the critical path and does not stop the other components from loading. All these should help improve your page speed.